# Commenting out an '=begin' in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments

I have a block of code that I need to comment out on occasion (pending a function that will do this automatically.)

Rather than searching each time for the correct lines to comment, I want to save the `=begin` and `=end` in place, prepending them with a `#` until the next time I need them.  For example:

```
def email_all_clients
#=begin - use this when no emails should be sent
   lines of code
#=end
end
```

Does this seem to be a safe approach?

Comment: "Safe" in what sense? Wouldn't it make more sense to control it via a flag or something and avoid source modification at all?

Answer (score 0):

No, you probably want to use an environment variable. You would restart the server after changing it, and need to restart Spring if you are using it.

If you are using the console, you would use

```
SEND_EMAILS=true rails c
```

In your code,

```
def email_all_clients
  return unless ENV['SEND_EMAILS']

  lines of code
end
```

Note, that `SEND_EMAILS=false` will also send emails, so don't use that.